# Bluetooth devices wake Mac OS X persistently

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have a MacBook Pro running latest El Capitan and in the Bluetooth preferences pane I have set up that Bluetooth devices shouldn't be able to wake up the Mac. However, recently I have been finding my Mac overheated when I wake it from sleep. I observed the situation a bit, removed all USB devices and looked at Activity Monitor and the processes preventing from sleep were "rcd" and "hidd". After having put the laptop to sleep, the fans go completely silent for half a minute and then they start spinning. As soon as the fans start spinning either the keyboard's or trackpad's green LED turns on without any obvious input. A minute later the fans stop and that cycles until I wake it up.

Comment: Take a look at [this site](http://triviaware.com/macprocess/all#H) for a list of all OS X processes. It looks like it might be some other remote process waking up your Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling OS X fixed it in case anyone has the same problem.